# Custom wp_query loop pattern

Tags: wordpress, loops

This is the pattern that i'm trying to achieve with wp_query. 
It's going to be for the same post type. Is it possible to do so with wp_query?

Thank you!

```
        <div>

          <div>1st post from featured</div>

          <div>1st post not from featured</div>

          <div>2nd post from featured</div>

          <div>3rd post from featured</div>

          <div>2nd post not from featured</div>

          <div>3rd post not from featured</div>

          ..and then the same pattern start again with the rest of the posts

          <div>4th post from featured</div>

          <div>4th post not from featured</div>

          <div>5th post from featured</div>

          <div>6th post from featured</div>

          <div>5th post not from featured</div>

          <div>6th post not from featured</div>

          ..until there's no more post
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It becomes slightly more complicated. We need two WP_Query objects, some calculations and a for-loop.

For PHP to know about the right format, we can use a simple format array. In following example, I will be using categories to determine the two WP_Query builds.

First, we build the base variables:

```
<?php 

    // Build format
    // 0 means not featured - 1 means featured.
    $format = array(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0);

    // Retrieve normal posts EXCLUDING category with ID 11 (Featured)
    $normal_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 999,
        'cat'            => '-11'
    ));

    // Retrieve featured posts ONLY INCLUDING category with ID 11 (Featured)
    $featured_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 999,
        'cat'            => 11
    ));

    // Calculate total amount of posts
    // from our two WP_Query results
    $posts_total = $normal_posts->post_count + $featured_posts;

    // Setup current post index
    $post_index = 0;
```

Next, we start 'the loop' or iteration:

```
    // Iterate every post from two queries
    for($i = 0; $i < $posts_total; $i++){
```

In which we calculate current format index:

```
        // Calculate which type of post to display based on post index
        // We use modulo to get the right $format index
        $post_format_index = $post_index % count($format);
        $current_format    = $format[$post_format_index];
```

Finally, display the right type of post:

```
        // Display to frontend based on format
        switch ($current_format) {
            case 1:
                // Featured
                $featured_posts->the_post();

                the_title();

                // Your content

                print '<br>';
                break;

            default:
                // Not Featured
                $normal_posts->the_post();

                the_title();

                // Your content

                print '<br>';
                break;
        }

        $post_index++;
    }

?>
```

That's it. You could take this a step further by adding another WP_Query and format.

```
$format = array(1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2);
```